# Determining bounds on a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My region of integration is $x^2 \leq y \leq 1$.  I understand that if I integrate a function $f(x,y)$ over this region by first integrating with respect to $x$, then the correct bounds are $\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} f(x,y) dx dy$.  And I know that I can integrate first w.r.t. $y$ as follows: $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{x^2}^1 f(x,y) dy dx$.  But my question is: why aren't the bounds of the interior integral allowed to be from 0 to $x^2$?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Drawing a picture will help! I have added an answer - let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, here's a picture of the region of integration - call it $S \subset \Bbb R^2$ (where blue and red overlap):

[image]

1. If you intersect a horizontal strip (of infinitesimal width) with $S$ at height $y$, you can check that the $x$-coordinates of points in this intersection vary from $-\sqrt y$ to $\sqrt y$. These are the limits in the first integral.
2. On the other hand, if you intersect a vertical strip (of infinitesimal width) with $S$ at a distance $x$ from the $Y$-axis, you can check that the $y$-coordinates of points in this strip vary from $x^2$ to $1$. This determines the limits of the second integral - namely $x^2$ to $1$ for the variable $y$. Clearly, $0$ to $x^2$ would not work, as points with $y$-coordinate $<x^2$ are not in $S$, the region of integration.

Comment: It's clear now!  Thank you very much @stoic-santiago!

Answer (score 0):

Just for some computational mathematical culture.... in *Mathematica*:

```
CylindricalDecomposition[x^2 < y < 1, {y, x}]
```

gives

$0<y<1\land -\sqrt{y}<x<\sqrt{y}$

[image]